# Pascal Triangle implementation in C#

Tags: c#, array

This is my attempt to implement the Pascal Triangle in C#. It is meant to calculate and return a pascal triangle of size `n` (which it takes is through the parameter `rows`).

```
static List<List<int>> GetPascalTriangle(int rows)
{
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++)
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == 1)
        {
            result.Add(Enumerable.Repeat(1, x + 1).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> prevRow = result[x - 1];
            List<int> semiResult = new List<int>();
            semiResult.Add(1);
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 <= prevRow.Count - 2; x1++)
            {
                semiResult.Add(prevRow[x1] + prevRow[x1 + 1]);
            }
            semiResult.Add(1);
            result.Add(semiResult);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I feel this code is a little messy. Thus I seek some opinion on it and ways to improve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: The Pascal Triangle will grow very rapidly. And `rows=100`, your maximum value is `1.27388061294904e+28`. Yes, that's right it will overflow `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` within 100 rows. Check it out on [interactive pascal triangle site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170313182843/http://mathforum.org/dr.cgi/pascal.cgi?rows=100)
The only suggestion is [`Numerics.BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0) where there is no upperbound.

Second: Why are you using `List<List<int>>`? You can use a jagged array, which is much shorter: `int[][]`, and effectively does the same. You just need to initialize them ahead with their size

```
var triangle = new int[rows][];
for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++){triangle[i] = new int[i+1];}
```

Third: if you know the first and last element is always a 1, then the if-statement for the first 2 rows is redundant

```
// This part is redundant, you already check if the first/last element is 1
if (x == 0 || x == 1)
{
    result.Add(Enumerable.Repeat(1, x + 1).ToList());
}
```

So with all the improvements, you code would be shorter and could handle much more rows. As a bonus I removed the dependency on system.linq. It could look like this:

```
public static BigInteger[][] GetPascalTriangleImproved(int rows)
    {
        BigInteger[][] result = new BigInteger[rows+1][];
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            result[x] = new BigInteger[x + 1];
            result[x][0] = 1; // first element is ALWAYS 1

            for (int x1 = 1; x1 <= x; x1++)
            {
                // last element is always 1 (just like the first)
                if (x1 == x) { result[x][x] = 1; continue; }

                // in all other cases, just add the 2 digits in the upper row
                result[x][x1] = result[x - 1][x1 - 1] + result[x - 1][x1];
            }                
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can speed it up a titch by removing the `if (x1 == x) { result[x][x] = 1; continue; }` out of the inner `for` loop and just have `result[x][x] = 1;` at the bottom of the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Malachi's suggestion,

**Equivalent Conditions**:

The condition `x <= rows - 1` is equivalent to `x < rows` which is shorter and *technically* more efficient (though I'm fairly certain the compiler would optimize this).

**Guard Statements**:

A common way I clean up my code is to use guard-statements instead of if/else. They're not always possible but something like this could reduce nesting. Just be aware this doesn't work in every case (as it may make some situations more confusing) but when it does work it can make code a lot less of an eye-sore.

```
if (x == 0 || x == 1)
{
    result.Add(Enumerable.Repeat(1, x + 1).ToList());
    continue;
}

var prevRow = result[x - 1];
var semiResult = new List<int>();
semiResult.Add(1);
for (int y = 0; y < prevRow.Count - 1; y++)
{
    semiResult.Add(prevRow[y] + prevRow[y + 1]);
}
semiResult.Add(1);
result.Add(semiResult);
```

**var keyword**:

It isn't uncommon to make use of the `var` keyword. Particularly in cases where it is obvious what the variables type is. e.g. `var semiResult = new List<int>();` this way you don't have to type 'List' twice.

Comment: Any suggestion on the implementation algorithm?

Comment: Honestly not much of an algorithm kind of guy (I lean towards architecture). So I can't say much there, I might have used arrays instead of lists since you know the number of rows from the start.

Comment: Yeah the only thing I'm seeing with your algorithm is the overhead of using a list instead of an array.

Comment: With arrays, i would need a separate counter to assign elements to. Would arrays over lists be a significant optimization?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists). And arrays do seem to be faster. I'll wait for some other opinions on the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The iteration variable on the inside of this function that you have named `x1` should be named `y` or at least something a little more distinguishing, it is a little confusing have `x` and then `x1`.

This line:

> ```
> for (int x1 = 0; x1 <= prevRow.Count - 2; x1++)
> ```

you should change the conditional statement so it is more clear, `less than or equal to 2 less than the previous rows count`.  make it less than the previous row count minus 1.

```
for (int y = 0; y < prevRow.Count - 1; y++)
```

---

These little changes are not so much about code efficiency as they are about being able to read the code more efficiently.

if you said this out loud `x1 <= prevRow.count - 2` it would be

> x one less than or equal to prevRow dot count minus 2

versus `y < prevRow.count - 1`

> y less than prevRow dot count minus 1

it is the same things but with less clutter, so it is easier to read, and if you keep in mind that *less than* is not an *equal to*, which you should know no matter what, you shouldn't have any issues.

another place where you have this is in your if statement here.

> ```
> if (x == 0 || x == 1)
> ```

let's just say it like this instead

```
if (x < 2)
```

---